# Path not found with Python : may double backslashes be the cause?

Tags: python, excel, path

The main purpose of this program is to open an Excel file, and to do different things with it.

I developed it on my own computer, and it works without any problem. Now that it works perfectly, I decided to install Spyder on the office commputer. Spyder and Python work, but I have a big problem : the path to the Excel file can't be found by Python.

I tried different locations on the computer, but wherever I put the file, it can't be found.
I finally decided to put it on the desktop, to make the things clearer and easier.

I tried to do this :

```
import os
desktop=os.path.join(os.environ['HOMEPATH'], 'Desktop')
print(desktop)
```

and it returns

```
\Users\supervision2\Desktop
```

Then, I add

```
print(os.listdir(desktop))
```

in order to see if the file is actually located on the desktop, but it returns :

```
Specified path can't be found : '\\Users\\supervision2\\Desktop'
```

It seems that the problem comes from the double backslashes : I know that Python put them automatically and that the problem is not supposed to come from there but it is the only thing I see.

I have already seen a lot of topics about similar issues, and I tried all different tools mentioned :

- putting double backslashes in the path
- putting an 'r' in front of the path, for 'raw string'
- putting frontslashes ('/')

None of these solutions work for me.

I don't understand why it is impossible to find the file.
It is not locked, I can easily open it from the desktop.
Both computers (my own and the office one) run Windows 7 Pro and have the same version of Python (Python 3.x)

Thanks for reading and for helping!

Comment: You should build an absolute path. The current working directory to check this relative path might not be what you think it is and you can only avoid that by making sure you're building an absolute path.

Comment: As @mpf82 mentioned please try with Absolute path : print(os.listdir(r'C:\\Users\\supervision2\\Desktop))

Comment: …assuming, of course, this file resides on drive C: